# How do I replace (NOT dual-boot) Windows XP with Lubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu, windows-xp

I'm not a technie; I don't know anything about coding. I'm a somewhat basic computer user. However, now that Microsoft has phased out support for Windows XP, I HAVE to change OSs. However, I don't have the money for buying a new computer, so I read some articles, and I learned about Lubuntu: a supposedly lightweight XP-esque OS.

But here's the thing: I don't know how to install Lubuntu. I also don't want to dual-boot, so I have to replace XP with the new OS. And although I have a 4 GiB flashdrive, I don't have a burnable or writable CD.

So, how do I do this...? I'm not experienced in this field... I wish there was an installer wizard or whatever that could do all that for me: eliminate XP from my computer, then install Lubuntu onto it.

Please help me? Any help at ALL would be GREATLY appreciated...

Thank you.

Computer Specs: Microsoft Windows XP Professional Ver. 2002, SP3 (32-bit)

Btw, I checked my Hard Drive space and RAM space: I do have the min. requirements covered.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to install *buntu series operating system, go to official website (Lubuntu = http://lubuntu.net ) and go to download section, check your pc architecture (32 or 64 bit).

You can download directly or via torrent. After you finished download the installer (have *.iso extension) You can burn it to bootable live CD or use flash drive. If you want to use flash drive you can download UNetbootin (Have Windows or Linux version) or Universal USB installer (Windows only), then open it and choose your linux distribution and locate your Lubuntu installer. Then click Create and wait until finished.

Reboot your PC and go to BIOS (try to press f2, f10, f12. Usually written on the screen), then make first boot order is your flash drive or Bootable CD.

If you download Lubuntu in the first time choose your language. then choose try Lubuntu if you want to test Lubuntu without install it or Install Lubuntu.

You can install Lubuntu beside your WinXP or use entire disk, if you want to dual boot with WinXP you must specify how much storage will be allocated for your Lubuntu. then click next or install (I'm forget). Set your keyboard bla bla bla, next you need to fill some basic information like your computer name, your name, username, and password. click install and wait until finish and unplug your flash drive or remove your CD. Reboot

Answer (score 0):

Go [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/GetLubuntu) and download the 32 bit version of lubuntu. On this old of a computer I doubt it will boot from a flash drive if it will you can use  [netbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) to create a bootable ubuntu flash drive.

If it will not boot from a flash drive you will have to [burntheisoimage](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto) to cd.

Back up any files you want to keep and the reformat your hard drive using the lubuntu install disk.

Guide to install [lubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/InstallingLubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

- What you need is to boot from lubuntu so you have 2 choices, either you copy lubuntu on your flash drive and boot from this flash, or you burn lubuntu.iso on another PC and boot from from CD/DVD.
- Next step: lubuntu setup wizard will guide you, it's simple don't worry at all.

Now when it comes on which partition you will install lubuntu, delete XP partition (You can know it from the size of partition), then create a small partition 250 mb and make it a "swap" partition, the rest of XP deleted partition you gonna create it as extended partition and put the root on "/".

- then click next and the rest you can do it by your self.